# MySQL insert - specialized action for "on duplicate"

Tags: mysql

I've been playing around with compound primary keys and unique indexes trying to get this to work correctly but getting nowhere fast.

I'm trying to create an insert sequence that adds totally new records, ignores totally duplicate records, and for records with duplicate key different value, I want to flag the old record as deleted (with a delete_id) and insert the new one.

Say this is the existing table...

```
group  | item  | value  | delete_id
-----------------------------------
group1 | item1 | 123    | null
group2 | item1 | 129    | null
group2 | item2 | 137    | null
group2 | item3 | 155    | null
group3 | item1 | 167    | null
```

And I want to insert the following records

```
group  | item  | value  
-----------------------
group2 | item1 | 129    (duplicate)
group2 | item2 | 9999   (different value)
group2 | item4 | 1      (new item)
```

I want the result to look like this

```
group  | item  | value  | delete_id
-----------------------------------
group1 | item1 | 123    | null
group2 | item1 | 129    | null  (duplicate unaffected)
group2 | item2 | 137    | 1     (flag delete)
group2 | item3 | 155    | null 
group3 | item1 | 167    | null
group2 | item2 | 9999   | null  (new insert)
group2 | item4 | 1      | null  (new insert)
```

What's more, each time a whole group will be inserted so any items not in the new insert should also be marked as deleted....
I want the result to look like this

```
group  | item  | value  | delete_id
-----------------------------------
group1 | item1 | 123    | null
group2 | item1 | 129    | null  (duplicate unaffected)
group2 | item2 | 137    | 1     (flag delete - replaced)
group2 | item3 | 155    | 1     (flag delete - omitted)
group3 | item1 | 167    | null
group2 | item2 | 9999   | null  (new insert)
group2 | item4 | 1      | null  (new insert)
```

Comment: Can you skim over your data again? I think there's a mistake. Where did `item1 | 137` come form in the third block?

Comment: do you mean `group2 | item2 | 137`?  That was in the original data.  It gets flagged deleted because  `group2 | item2 | 9999` was inserted

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique constraint on `group`, `item` and `value`.

```
ALTER TABLE `yourTable` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index` (`group`, `item`, `value`);
```

Before updating a group set the `delete_id` flag to `1`.

```
UPDATE `yourTable` SET `delete_id` = 1 WHERE `group` = "group2";
```

Then update the group with :

```
INSERT INTO `yourTable` (`group`, `item`, `value`)
VALUES
  ("group2", "item1", 129),
  ("group2", "item2", 9999),
  ("group2", "item4", 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  `delete_id` = null;
```

Have a look at the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9cb8/1).

Comment: very nice but I should have mentioned the delete_id is a reference to a session table.  Once a record is "deleted" it must not be updated.  So I think just including the delete_id in the unique index will solve that problem.

Comment: I was trying to avoid writing data to all the "old" duplicates since the vast majority of the updates will be duplicates and actual inserts will be rare.  But the solution I was working on (adding a column for last_check_id, then going back and "deleting" the ones without the current last_check_id) also involved updating basically every record in the table.  This is easier to understand and avoids a bogus column.  Can this be simplified with triggers?

Comment: regarding the part about _Once a record is "deleted" it must not be updated_, a test would be to insert a record that changes the value, then insert another record that changes it back. This should result in two "deleted" records and one latest, as opposed to "undeleting" the first record